# Dynamically change celery beat schedule params

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat, djcelery

I get schedule values from .env file. And sometimes parameters in .env file change.
Is it possible to change schedule values of already running celery beat tasks?

My celery.py:

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from dotenv import load_dotenv


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproj.settings')

app = Celery('myproj')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()


load_dotenv()
orders_update_time = float(os.getenv("ORDERS_UPDATE_TIME"))
if not orders_update_time:
    orders_update_time = 60.0

orders_update_time = float(os.getenv("REMAINS_SEND_TIME"))
if not remains_send_time:
    remains_send_time = 60.0



app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'wb_orders_autosaver': {
        'task': 'myapp.tasks.orders_autosave',
        'schedule': orders_update_time,
    },
    'wb_remains_autosender': {
        'task': 'myapp.tasks.remains_autosend',
        'schedule': remains_send_time,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use [django-celery-beat](https://pypi.org/project/django-celery-beat/).  That will allow you to save your schedule to the database and you can use the django admin ui to modify the schedule.

---

From django shell_plus, you can run the following commands to create your schedule:

```
schedule = CrontabSchedule(minute='0', hour='10')
schedule.save()
PeriodicTask.objects.create(
    crontab=schedule,
    task='myapp.tasks.orders_autosave',
    name='autosave orders',
)
schedule = CrontabSchedule(minute='15', hour='10')
schedule.save()
PeriodicTask.objects.create(
    crontab=schedule,
    task='myapp.tasks.remains_autosend',
    name='autosend remains',
)
PeriodicTasks.changed()
```

Or you can use the UI in the django admin panel:

1. Select add periodic task

[image: periodic tasks]

2. Enter in the information about your task and select save

[image]

Comment: I installed this package. Could you show a simple usage example. On the example of my code.